# Requesting a great example of nested select / subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got to learn how to created nested selects / subqueries (are they the same thing??) and I'm having a tough time finding a great learning spot... any links to helpful tutorials / explanations??

I'm hoping I can learn so I don't have to rely on the geniuses here.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this two links  , its a good article  for T-sql  subqueries

> http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3485291/Using-a-Correlated-Subquery-in-a-T-SQL-Statement.htm
>
> http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_subqueries.html

Comment: Thank you very much - those were very helpful!!  I also found the page he referenced in the first link helpful: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3464481